# Rails, null value in column violates not-null constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In production, I have a model Category. When I try to create a category in the website I get the following error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
```

The migration looks like this

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.references :supercategory,     index: true
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    Category.create_translation_table! name: :string
  end
  ....
end
```

And the schema

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
    t.string   "slug"
    t.index ["restaurant_id"], name: "index_categories_on_restaurant_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_categories_on_slug", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["supercategory_id"], name: "index_categories_on_supercategory_id", using: :btree
  end
```

Any ideas what might be causing the error? Thanks!
If you need more code just ask.

EDIT
The params sent

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"no3uGNSYkgClG+y6y9Y=",
>   "category"=>{"name"=>"Coffee", "age_restriction"=>"0",
>   "available_all_day"=>"0", "supercategory_id"=>"",
>   "avatar"=>#,
>   @original_filename="coffee.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg",
>   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"category[avatar]\";
>   filename=\"coffee.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">},
>   "commit"=>"Create Category", "remotipart_submitted"=>"true",
>   "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", "X-Http-Accept"=>"text/javascript,
>   application/javascript, application/ecmascript,
>   application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01",
>   "restaurant_id"=>"kilimanjaro-coffee"}

EDIT
I tried to create a category from the console and I found that the model does not have a name column. Seems like it has not been migrated properly. I dropped, created and migrated the database again but the column still does not appear. Any ideas where does that come from?

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint to your controller and inspect the new `Category` object before it is saved?

Comment: I am in production and the bug only appears there. I added the params sent.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to imagine how you could get that error without the PostgreSQL table having that column set to be not null, so I suspect that you are not using the database that you think you are using.

You can check which columns active record believes are set to not null with this:

```
Category.columns.reject{|c| c.null}.map(&:name)
```

Comment: The ouput of your command was => ["id", "created_at", "updated_at"].
I believe the not null requirement comes from the Category model where I have validates :name, presence: true

Comment: That would not raise an ActiveRecord PG error, though. You'd get an error on #save! but #save (no bang on the end) would simply return false.

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm out of ideas.